# How can i correct this error(The package is configured with translation errors)?

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is the question

-Create customers table and add these columns:
Id
Name
AGE
ADDRESS
SALARY
-Add 10 rows.
-Create a package with three procedures:
one that add a customer to the table.
one that removes a customer from the table.
one that lists all the customers.
-Create customers table and add these columns:
Id
Name
AGE
ADDRESS
SALARY
-Add 10 rows.
-Create a package with three procedures:
one that add a customer to the table.
one that removes a customer from the table.
one that lists all the customers.

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
    customer_id      NUMBER NOT NULL,
    customer_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    customer_age    NUMBER NOT NULL,
    customer_address    VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    customer_salary    NUMBER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(customer_id)
);
INSERT INTO customer
VALUES 
              (1,'Ahemed',22,'wq1',2500);
INSERT INTO customer
VALUES
              (2,'salem',24,'wq2',2000);
 INSERT INTO customer
VALUES
              (3,'Aboud',26,'wq3',2200);
INSERT INTO customer
VALUES
              (4,'Tarek',27,'wq4',2100);
 INSERT INTO customer
VALUES
              (5,'Hazem',33,'wq5',3000);
INSERT INTO customer
VALUES
              (6,'Hayder',32,'wq6',2300);
INSERT INTO customer
VALUES
              (7, 'Sammy',35,'wq7',2700);
INSERT INTO customer
VALUES
              (8,'Mohammed',20,'wq8',4000);
 INSERT INTO customer
VALUES
              (9,'Tayseer',18,'wq9',3600);
 INSERT INTO customer
VALUES
              (10,'Hamoud',40,'wq10',3100);
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE mypackage AS
PROCEDURE add_customer(c_id      customer.customer_id%type,
                                    c_name      customer.customer_name%type,
                                   c_age      customer.customer_age%type,
                                   c_address      customer.customer_address%type,
                                   c_salary     customer.customer_salary%type);
      
PROCEDURE remove_customer(c_id  customer.customer_id%type);
PROCEDURE list_customer;
END mypackage ;
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY mypackage AS 
   PROCEDURE add_customer(c_id  customer.customer_id%type, 
      c_name customer.customer_name%type, 
      c_age  customer.customer_age%type, 
      c_address   customers.address%type,  
      c_salary     customer.customer_salary%type) 
   IS 
   BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO customer (customer_id ,customer_name,customer_age ,customer_address ,customer_salary) 
         VALUES(c_id, c_name, c_age, c_address, c_salary); 
   END add_customer;
   
   PROCEDURE remove_customer(c_id   customer.customer_id%type) IS 
   BEGIN 
      DELETE FROM customer
      WHERE  customer_id= c_id; 
   END remove_customer;
   PROCEDURE  list_customer(customer_id ,customer_name,customer_age ,customer_address ,customer_salar) IS 
   BEGIN 
     select * from customer;
   END list_customer;
```

If i create this package the error is(The package is configured with translation errors) how can i solve it?

Comment: I guess you've translated that error message, and it's the common "Warning: Package created with compilation errors". In Oracle's own tools you can do `show errors` after you see it; or query the `user_errors` view to see the problems, if the client doesn't show them anyway. But here, if you are running all of that code as a script, then you are missing the `/` on a line on its own [after each PL/SQL block](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SQL-Plus-basics.html#GUID-1C95D0FD-41A2-487A-A1F0-10509B8FC62C). Your package body also seems to be incomplete.

Comment: Is the syntax correct?

Comment: No, but once you get the spec and body to both compile properly, you'll be able to see the actual syntax errors, and then address those.

Comment: can you solve it please? because my editor does not support it

Comment: Which editor, and what doesn't it support? Just the `show errors` command? You can query the `user_errors` view from any client. You will need to learn how to find and understand the actual errors behind this message, because you will be seeing it a lot as you write other code. Just telling you how to write this one package won't help you in the long term; but Littlefoot's answer will get you a lot further.

Answer (score 1):

Table and package specification are OK (kind of):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE customer(
  2      customer_id      NUMBER NOT NULL,
  3      customer_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  4      customer_age    NUMBER NOT NULL,
  5      customer_address    VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  6      customer_salary    NUMBER NOT NULL,
  7      PRIMARY KEY(customer_id)
  8  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE mypackage AS
  2  PROCEDURE add_customer(c_id      customer.customer_id%type,
  3                                      c_name      customer.customer_name%type,
  4                                     c_age      customer.customer_age%type,
  5                                     c_address      customer.customer_address%type,
  6                                     c_salary     customer.customer_salary%type);
  7
  8  PROCEDURE remove_customer(c_id  customer.customer_id%type);
  9  PROCEDURE list_customer;
 10  END mypackage ;
 11  /

Package created.
```

But then, for some reason, you didn't follow the same *recipe* for package body:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY mypackage AS
  2     PROCEDURE add_customer(c_id  customer.customer_id%type,
  3        c_name customer.customer_name%type,
  4        c_age  customer.customer_age%type,
  5        c_address   customers.address%type,
  6        c_salary     customer.customer_salary%type)
  7     IS
  8     BEGIN
  9        INSERT INTO customer (customer_id ,customer_name,customer_age ,customer_address ,customer_salary)
 10           VALUES(c_id, c_name, c_age, c_address, c_salary);
 11     END add_customer;
 12
 13     PROCEDURE remove_customer(c_id   customer.customer_id%type) IS
 14     BEGIN
 15        DELETE FROM customer
 16        WHERE  customer_id= c_id;
 17     END remove_customer;
 18
 19     PROCEDURE  list_customer(customer_id ,customer_name,customer_age ,customer_address ,customer_salar) IS
 20     BEGIN
 21       select * from customer;
 22     END list_customer;
 23  end mypackage;
 24  /

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.
```

What's wrong?

```
SQL> show err
Errors for PACKAGE BODY MYPACKAGE:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
19/41    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the
         following:
         in out <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
         table ... columns long double ref char standard time
         timestamp interval date binary national character nchar

20/4     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of
         the following:
         not null of nan infinite dangling a empty json

SQL>
```

Line #19 is wrong:

```
 19     PROCEDURE  list_customer(customer_id ,customer_name,customer_age ,customer_address ,customer_salar) IS
```

So: if - apparently - you do know how to use parameters while declaring procedures, why didn't you do the same for `list_customer`? Besides, it wouldn't work anyway - in PL/SQL, a SELECT must have an INTO (and your procedure doesn't). I guess that at `customer_id` should be passed as a parameter (so I'm doing that in my example).

Moreover, all procedures you declare in package specification must exist in package body, with exactly the same description (you've used `customer.address%type` but that column doesn't exist in the table).

---

So, when fixed: specification:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE mypackage AS
  2  PROCEDURE add_customer(c_id      customer.customer_id%type,
  3                                      c_name      customer.customer_name%type,
  4                                     c_age      customer.customer_age%type,
  5                                     c_address      customer.customer_address%type,
  6                                     c_salary     customer.customer_salary%type);
  7
  8  PROCEDURE remove_customer(c_id  customer.customer_id%type);
  9  PROCEDURE list_customer (p_customer_id customer.customer_id%type);
 10  END mypackage ;
 11  /

Package created.
```

Body:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY mypackage AS
  2  PROCEDURE add_customer(c_id      customer.customer_id%type,
  3                                      c_name      customer.customer_name%type,
  4                                     c_age      customer.customer_age%type,
  5                                     c_address      customer.customer_address%type,
  6                                     c_salary     customer.customer_salary%type)
  7                                     IS
  8     BEGIN
  9        INSERT INTO customer (customer_id ,customer_name,customer_age ,customer_address ,customer_salary)
 10           VALUES(c_id, c_name, c_age, c_address, c_salary);
 11     END add_customer;
 12
 13     PROCEDURE remove_customer(c_id   customer.customer_id%type) IS
 14     BEGIN
 15        DELETE FROM customer
 16        WHERE  customer_id= c_id;
 17     END remove_customer;
 18
 19     PROCEDURE  list_customer(p_customer_id in customer.customer_id%type)
 20     --,customer_name,customer_age ,customer_address ,customer_salar) IS
 21     is
 22       l_row customer%rowtype;
 23     BEGIN
 24       select * into l_row from customer where customer_id = p_customer_id;
 25     END list_customer;
 26  end mypackage;
 27  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```

This, at least, compiles. Does it do what you wanted it, I didn't try - I'll leave it to you.

Comment: Ok thank you very much... what type of editor do you use in oracle?

Comment: You're welcome. For GUI, I use SQL Developer (Oracle's free tool, download it from OTN). Demo in this answer is based on SQL*Plus (command-line tool, part of any Oracle database installation).

Comment: OK...thanks...do you have a course link on procedures stored  in (pl_sql oracle with c#) because i have a project i want to apply stored procedures (delete,update,add and searching) in my project... or sample project from githup about it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have it; I know nothing about C#.

Comment: ok thanks...  last questions... if i add this to my questions.(1-Within the listing procedure use a cursor, and a nested table.

2-Finally, call the package and its methods in another pl/sql block. how can i do it?

Comment: **1)** No problem, you can use a cursor. Nested table? What for? Everything depends on what the "listing" actually does. Displaying the result using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE? Return the result to the caller? If so, maybe a **function** that returns refcursor or a collection would be a better idea. **2)** Calling procedures require PL/SQL, while you can call functions from both SQL and PL/SQL.

Comment: can you explain it with code please?